iommu & QLogic NetXtreme II BCM57840
I have virtualized the opnsense and pass-through QLogic NetXtreme II BCM57840  via iommu.
I can't get both the ports work, one of them works but the other has the problem with the address mapping. I am just wondering if someone else has faced the same problem, the logs are as follow, please guide !
If I insert the card in the other PCI-express slot the bxe0 starts working and bxe1 start having the problem which is mentioned below for bxe0
bxe0: <QLogic NetXtreme II BCM57840 4x10GbE (B1) BXE v:1.78.91> mem 0x380000000000-0x3800007fffff,0x380000800000-0x380000ffffff,0x380002000000-0x38000200ffff irq 10 at device 9.0 on pci0
bxe0: PCI BAR0 [10] memory allocated: 0x380000000000-0x3800007fffff (8388608) -> 0xfffffe008d400000
bxe0: PCI BAR2 [18] memory allocated: 0x380000800000-0x380000ffffff (8388608) -> 0xfffffe008dc00000
bxe0: PCI BAR4 [20] memory allocated: 0x380002000000-0x38000200ffff (65536) -> 0xfffffe0084678000
bxe0: ERROR: Invalid SHMEM validity signature: 0x00010008
bxe0: ERROR: Invalid phy config in NVRAM (PHY1=0x00010008 PHY2=0x00010008)
bxe0: Unknown media!
bxe0: IFMEDIA flags : 20
bxe0: Using defaults for TSO: 65518/35/2048
bxe0: ERROR: FW failed to respond!
bxe0: ERROR: MCP response failure, aborting
bxe0: ERROR: Failed to unload previous driver! time_counter 10 rc -1
bxe1: <QLogic NetXtreme II BCM57840 4x10GbE (B1) BXE v:1.78.91> mem 0x380001000000-0x3800017fffff,0x380001800000-0x380001ffffff,0x380002010000-0x38000201ffff irq 10 at device 10.0 on pci0
bxe1: PCI BAR0 [10] memory allocated: 0x380001000000-0x3800017fffff (8388608) -> 0xfffffe008e800000
bxe1: PCI BAR2 [18] memory allocated: 0x380001800000-0x380001ffffff (8388608) -> 0xfffffe008f000000
bxe1: PCI BAR4 [20] memory allocated: 0x380002010000-0x38000201ffff (65536) -> 0xfffffe0084688000
bxe1: Found 10Gb Fiber media.
bxe1: IFMEDIA flags : 20
bxe1: Using defaults for TSO: 65518/35/2048
bxe1: Ethernet address: d4:5d:64:09:0b:6a
bxe1: MSI-X vectors Requested 2 and Allocated 2

Any ideas ?
